# Summary statistics table in R with multiple vertical variables, subvariables, panels, subpanels, etc

Tags: r, statistics, latex, summary, stargazer

Apologies for the rather general question, but I tried to use stargazer and other packages and I still cannot work my way around to build an advanced summary statistics table in R. I am working with the following dataset:

```
> str(df_All)
tibble [5,064 × 29] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Net_IRR              : num [1:5064] 15.9 1.75 46 20 18.4 ...
 $ Age                  : num [1:5064] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Ln_Age               : num [1:5064] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Fund_Sequence        : num [1:5064] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Ln_Fund_Sequence     : num [1:5064] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Fund_Size            : num [1:5064] 50 46 423 96.9 81 ...
 $ Ln_Fund_Size         : num [1:5064] 3.91 3.83 6.05 4.57 4.39 ...
 $ Nr_Funds             : num [1:5064] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ HHI_Industry         : num [1:5064] 0.427 0.243 0.36 0.333 1 ...
 $ HHI_Region           : num [1:5064] 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Stock_Market_Returns : num [1:5064] 0.11936 -0.00711 -0.00643 -0.03869 -0.01931 ...
 $ GDP_Growth           : num [1:5064] 0.0284 0.0245 0.0261 0.0304 0.0104 ...
 $ Net_Multiple         : num [1:5064] 3.3 1.09 4.04 2.73 1.95 ...
 $ Ln_Fund_Size^2       : num [1:5064] 15.3 14.7 36.6 20.9 19.3 ...
 $ Size_Q1              : num [1:5064] 41.5 42.5 123.8 109.8 85.5 ...
 $ Size_Q2              : num [1:5064] 125.8 92.8 325.5 232 177.3 ...
 $ Size_Q3              : num [1:5064] 211 206 756 624 302 ...
 $ Size_Q4              : num [1:5064] 1000 1500 6114 5887 2600 ...
 $ Size_Spline_1        : num [1:5064] 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ Size_Spline_2        : num [1:5064] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Size_Spline_3        : num [1:5064] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ Size_Spline_4        : num [1:5064] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Dummy_First_Time_Fund: num [1:5064] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Dummy_Industry       : num [1:5064] 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ Dummy_Region         : num [1:5064] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Fund_ID              : num [1:5064] 8360 3491 5576 48689 6016 ...
 $ Vintage_Year         : num [1:5064] 2002 2004 2000 1997 2006 ...
 $ Asset_Class          : chr [1:5064] "Venture Capital" "Venture Capital" "Private Equity" "Private Equity" ...
 $ Region_Focus         : chr [1:5064] "North America" "North America" "North America" "Europe" ...
```

I would like to build a summary statistics table with a Latex format. The data should be aggregated by the following vertical/horizontal groups/sub groups:

- Vertical dimensions:

  - Number of funds
  - Fund size ($mn)
  - IRR (%)
  - Multiple (x)
- Vertical subdimensions (for each variable):

  - Median
  - Mean
  - Min
  - Max
  - Standard Deviation
- Horizontal panels (data to divide in sub samples):

  - Whole sample
  - Private Equity
  - Private Debt
  - Real Estate
  - Infrastructure
- Horizontal subdimensions (for each panel):

  - Regional focus

    - North America
    - Europe
    - Other (counting all other regions)
  - Fund size

    - < $100 mn
    - 100 to $500 mn
    - $500mn to $1bn
    - more than $1bn
  - Fund sequence

    - 1
    - 2–3
    - 4-5
    - more than 5
  - #Funds
  - Age
  - HHI Industry
  - HHI Region

I hope my issue is clear and would highly appreciate any help!

The aimed output is something along these lines:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUWNU.png)

Comment: There are szillions of similar questions, even with answers. Some of them are very good asked, providing a self contained example. Please use the search function, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the `datasummary` from `modelsummary` package. You can split vertical and horizontal easily. Please provide a minimal example of your data, if you need more help. It would be easier to replicate what you ask for, when you provide the data.

```
library(modelsummary)

data(mtcars)

datasummary(factor(cyl) * (mpg + drat) ~ factor(vs)*(Mean + Min + Max + SD), 
            data = mtcars)
```

[image]